# Can I make the browser tab of the website I'm programing have no text

Tags: html, browser, tabs, html-title

I want my website to not have text in the browser tab when you open it.
So I want to do something like this:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/n1ozrn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Don't put anything in the title tag in your documents `<head>`

```
<title> </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<title>&#65279;</title>
```